# How to track Content Views with Google Analytics iOS SDK

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm just implementing the Google Analytics iOS SDK. The issue i have is that Google offers this types of tracking.

```
Campaigns
Crashes and Exceptions
Custom Dimensions & Metrics
ECommerce
Events
Screens
Sessions
Social Interactions
```

Now i have a "MeidaPlayer" ViewController which plays videos. With "Screens" i can track that the "MeidaPlayer" Screen viewed but how can i track which video was selected/played?

Events are not the right thing for that i think.

Comment: Why do you think Events are not the right thing? In fact if you look at events examples from the official docs, video plays is exactly what they use as an example.

Comment: Oh i see they do for web, i was looking at iOS SDK. Than you, so i guess Events are the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Events, like Eduardo suggested.

Comment: I ended up putting it as part of the Label string. Somthing like "/61/My-Video/" where 61 would be the ID.